# Accessing a variable from an unrelated function in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, wrapper, access-specifier

I want to access a variable of one class into another class, and set it to some value, e.g. like in code here, i wanna set the `some_flag` to `true` in the `secondClassFunction()`. Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Constraints due to system architecture:

1. The two classes are not inheritable.
2. The two classes are not related either.
3. The function signatures of `secondClassFunction()`cannot be changed.

Here's the code snippet:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class FirstClass{
    bool some_flag;
    public:
        void setFlag(bool flag);
        bool getFlag();
};

FirstClass::FirstClass(){
    some_flag(false);
}

class SecondClass{
    public:
        void secondClassFunction();
}

SecondClass::secondClassFunction(){
    // do something here.

    // I want to access some_flag using SecondClass object.
    // how to do this?
}

int main() {
    SecondClass secObj;
    secObj.secondClassFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Will wrapper classes help? If yes, how?

EDIT:-

Constraint 4. Cannot make the classes friend functions.

Constraint 5. Cannot globalize the flag variable.

Details:-

The `flag` is set in a function which is a member of `FirstClass`.
I wish to reset this `flag` in a function which is member of the `SecondClass`.
The two classes are not related, inheritable, and their access specifiers cannot be changed, due to constraints of the system architecture.

The `flag` is like a semaphore, it's used by multiple tasks, to denote the status of an activity, such as, whether the processor has received a certain command from a mobile app or not.

Comment: `friend` is your friend.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper no, `friend` is your *enemy*. Proper design is your friend.

Comment: You want to access `some_flag` of which object?

Comment: In order to help we'll need some more details on your problem. In particular: Where does the instance of FirstClass come from? What does some_flag do? Why are you unable to change anything about either class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not care about instance of the `FirstClass`. So the following approach will work for you:

```
void SecondClass::secondClassFunction()
{
    // Create local instance of the object to change
    FirstClass first;
    first.setFlag(true);
}
```

But it makes no sense at all. You need to know which object to modify. I'd suggest three options:

- make instance of `FirstClass` static, global or singleton and modify it
- make `some_flag` and its setter static
- set instance of the `FirstClass` to context before calling `SecondClass::secondClassFunction()`

Third option explained:

```
class FirstClass; // Forward declaration
 class SecondClass
{
...
    FirstClass* firstClassInstance;
...
    void setFirstClassInstanceToModify(FirstClass* first)
    {
        firstClassInstance = first;
    }
...
};

void SecondClass::secondClassFunction()
{
    firstClassInstance->setFlag(true);
}
```

And call it like this

```
FirstClass first;
...
SecondClass second;
...
second.setFirstClassInstanceToModify(&first);
second.secondClassFunction();
```

But make sure to have proper and valid instance before calling `secondClassFunction`